# Evitar Registros Duplicados al Importar de Excel a Sql Server C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy creando una aplicación **mvc 5** con `c#` (uso entity framework) y tengo un método donde importo datos de `excel` a `sql-server`(la importación la puedo hacer), pero me surge una dificultad el archivo de excel se tiene que importar cada semana y necesito controlar que los registros que ya existen no se vuelvan a copiar(evitar duplicados) quiero controlar esto mediante el campo id.
este es el código que uso para importar los datos.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + importExcel.file.FileName);
    importExcel.file.SaveAs(path);
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1'";
    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);


    excelConnection.Open();
    string tableName = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    excelConnection.Close();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + tableName + "]", excelConnection);
    excelConnection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    //Conexion para copiar datos
    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);

    //Nombre tabla BD
    sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Usuario"; 
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("id", "id");
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("nombre", "nombre");
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("apellido", "apellido");

    //otros campos
    sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    excelConnection.Close();

    ViewBag.Result = "Datos Importados";
}
```

Me podrían orientar como evitar que se dupliquen los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola como tal no creo que puedas,lo que si puedes hacer es crearte una tabla igual que solo te sirva para llenar con el excel podría llamarse "UsuarioExcel" ahí antes de insertar haces un TRUNCATE a la tabla y después insertas esos registros.

Después de eso podrías llamar a un sp que verifique esa tabla y con un MERGE o con otra lógica que desees puedes evaluar esa tabla contra la que tiene los datos y te pasas los datos que no tengas de UsuarioExcel hacia tu tabla Usuario

Saludos.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + importExcel.file.FileName);
                importExcel.file.SaveAs(path);
                string excelConnectionString = @"Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1'";
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);


                excelConnection.Open();
                string tableName = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables").Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                excelConnection.Close();

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" + tableName + "]", excelConnection);
                excelConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dReader;
                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    //Conexion para copiar datos
                    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString);
                    string SQL = "CREATE TABLE ##TempTableUsuarios(ID INT,nombre NVARCHAR(50),apellido NVARCHAR(50));";
                dbConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand EjecutarComando = new SqlCommand(SQL, dbConnection);
                EjecutarComando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //LOGICA DE COPIAR LOS DATOS
                //Nombre tabla BD
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "##TempTableUsuarios";
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("id", "id");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("nombre", "nombre");
                sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("apellido", "apellido");

                //otros campos
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                EjecutarComando.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO dbo.Usuarios (ID, nombre, apellido) 
                                        SELECT t.ID, t.nombre, t.apellido FROM ##TempTableUsuarios t 
                                        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Usuarios WHERE t.ID = ID);
                                        DROP TABLE ##TempTableUsuarios;";


                EjecutarComando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }

            excelConnection.Close();

            ViewBag.Result = "Datos Importados";
        }
```

Comment: He leído que se puede crear una tabla temporal con SqlBullcopy y luego se podria hacer un Insert Into con un Select aqui  hay un ejemplo https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/09cc626e-ed32-40ca-b4c9-1a240ba66775/evitar-que-se-dupliquen-los-registros-en-la-base-de-datos?forum=netfxes pero aho usan ado.net no se como seria el equivalente usando EF y Linq

Comment: Ya veo es algo como lo que te menciono de pasarlo a una tabla que tu tengas como repositorio insertar ahi y posteriormente hacen un select de los datos de se tiene del repo hacia la nueva donde no esten los otros datos

Comment: Te edito la respuesta con algo que quisas podrias usar checalo y me dices, como tal no lo puedo probar pero algo de este modo quedaria

Comment: Algo así estaba tratando de hacer pero me marca un error System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se puede tener acceso a la tabla de destino '#TempTable'.'    no me crea la tabla temporal

Comment: Si por que esa tabla con un # es al momento solo para la conexión que se abre por eso para usarlo en todos los ámbitos debe de ser con ##
Asi esta en el ejemplo que te anexe

Comment: funciona perfecto gracias, solo una ultima consulta como podria hacer para que si importan el archivo excel y no hay cambios(tiene los mismos regristros) muestre un mensaje(viewbaw o alert) que los registros son los mimos

Comment: Si lo quisieras así el insert de los datos tendría que ser a una tabla Normal y no una temporal, de este modo antes de pasar los datos hacemos un select de esta información en la base de datos y lo comparamos con la del excel y si es la misma se muestra el mensaje en caso de no ser asi continuas con el proceso normal.
Pero el hacerlo con la tabla temporal fue para solo pasar los datos y después se limpia la tabla para que cuando el excel regrese volver a cargar todo.